# A SHA verifier in the CNF format

Tags: hash

Can someone help tell how to generate a 3-CNF verifier for SHA-256 that:

1. outputs 1 if message/input's calculated SHA-256 value matches the pre-provided hash
2. Otherwise outputs 0.

Given that the message can be arbitrarily long we can assume it to have a finite length (say 2 MB)   to make our task simpler.

Comment: Except for the size of the CNF, there seems to be no salient difficulty. Do you see how you would do given a 3-CNF implementation of SHA-256 for fixed-size message? How you would build this given a 3-CNF implementation of a SHA-256 compression? How to build this from a 3-CNF implementation of a SHA-256 round? How to further break that into 3-CNF? Just start to do it, and if you get stuck, tell where.

Comment: thank you. just a follow up query. Can you suggest a good language and a circuit output program in the sense that given the high level binary operations it essentially outputs a boolean expression that implements the logic. VHDL or some other seem to be for designing circuits but i am unsure how can we get the binary logic [AND, OR, NOT] gates based output that implements the same. P.S. New to this thus somewhat clueless.

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend a tool. I once (2004) wanted to convert to CNF a crypto-related problem ([VMPC](http://www.vmpcfunction.com/vmpc.pdf)), tried to find easily used tools, failed, and ended up writing [a short C program](https://pastebin.com/WbDaYxWP). The benchmarks it generates are still used in the SAT competitions. The whole thing started to work in a single evening, IIRC.

Comment: not an issue. thanks a lot.